# How can I use the occurrences to calculate the end date of a recurring event in eas

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0, exchange-server, activesync, nodatime

Can anyone tell me the best way of calculating the end date of a recurring event from the number of occurrences and the pattern in which the event occurs.

For example:
I have an event which has start date as 10/07/2014 (Tuesday) and occurs every week on Tuesday. This event will end after 10 occurrences (say). So, the my method should return me the end date as : 12/09/2014

The method should also consider more complex situations like suppose if the event occurs yearly on first Monday of October and has total 10 occurrences.

Answer (score 6):

(This isn't an answer which gives you a complete solution by any means, but hopefully it's a step in the right direction.)

Good luck. I've worked on an ActiveSync implementation, and recurrent events are fundamentally painful. You'll need to think about all kinds of corner cases - if something occurs every month on the 30th, what happens in February? What happens if it happens at 1.30am, and the clocks go forward or backward in the event's time zone so that 1.30am happens 0 or 2 times for a particular day?

Noda Time can *help* with this, but it doesn't provide a complete solution, partly because all the requirements will vary so much.

The important types you'll need to know about are `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` to provide time-zone-neutral dates/times, and `Period` which represents a not-necessarily-fixed period of time, such as "1 month". That will help with things like "add a week" - and there are methods on `LocalDate` for things like "next Monday after this date". It gets harder for events which are "weekly, on Monday and Wednesday" - you'll want to step through the weeks, working out which days occur within a particular week, until you've gone through all the events you need.

Noda Time 2.0 has the concept of "adjusters" which will make life somewhat simpler for things like "the first Monday of October" but everything you need to do *can* be done with Noda Time 1.3. (Don't wait for Noda Time 2.0, which I wouldn't expect to be released for another 6 months at least.)

I think my strongest pieces of advice would be:

- Keep it simple. Focus on getting the right results first, then work out any optimizations you need. (For example, don't try to "guess" when the 100th instance of an event will occur - stepping through 100 instances with simple steps will be slower, but get you to the right answer. Do measure the performance, but make sure you have good tests before you optimize.)
- Introduce your own types to represent *exactly* what you know about the event. Use the Noda Time types where they match of course, but don't be tempted to use an existing type just because it's *quite* like what you're trying to represent. The small differences will bit you eventually.
- Make sure you know what you actually want the results to be. Write *lots* of tests. Date and time work is a naturally data-oriented domain, so invest in making it as easy as possible to write tests for all the corner cases you should be thinking of. (And you really *should* be thinking about them. Pay particular attention to leap years and time zones.)
- Be aware that time arithmetic doesn't follow the normal rules of arithmetic - `x + 1 month + 1 month` isn't the same as `x + 2 months`
- If/when behaviour surprises you, *do* come back to ask specific questions here. There aren't very many of us working on Noda Time, but questions tend to be answered quickly :)

Comment: Deleting my paltry answer in favor of this one :)

Comment: I feel so much better about having struggled with adding recurring appointments to the Exchange sync part of our system now. If Jon Skeet says it's hard, then it's not just me being a wimp!